# Connect to Vertica 7.0.1 from Spark 1.5.2/1.6.2

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vertica

I am trying to connect to vertica from spark. Below is my code:

```
val opt = Map("host" -> host , "table" -> table , "db" -> db , "numPartitions" -> partitions , "user" -> user , "password" -> pswd )
val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource").options(opt).load()
df1.show()
```

I am getting below error-

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.vertica.spark.datasource.DefaultSource. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
>       at com.ConnectToVertica$.main(ConnectToVertica.scala:32)
>       at com.ConnectToVertica.main(ConnectToVertica.scala)

I checked for the packages also (http://spark-packages.org) as indicated in the error but did not find any package for Vertica. If I execute the same code with spark-submit by passing the jars for Vertica its working fine but directly from IDE gives me this error.I tried with spark 1.6.2 also and getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not added the jar file in your class path. Download the jar from the below url, add to the classpath and try the same.

```
https://www.qzhou.com.cn/user/bdy/3477137749
```

I was the facing the same issue sometimes back where i was unable to find the hpe-spark connector.  Hopes this will help